# How can i remove all the dirctories except those what evar i mentioned in the output

Tags: unix, ksh

```
 drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 May 22 15:23 2018-05-22
drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 May 23 10:06 2018-05-23
drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 May 28 09:30 2018-05-28
drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 May 29 12:24 2018-05-29
-rw-r--r--    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER      48781 May 30 13:52 do.jck8b
-rw-r--r--    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER      48842 May 30 14:11 do.jck8b.64
drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 Jun  1 11:09 2018-06-01

i want only 4 files like this
```

sample output is..

```
drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 May 23 10:06 2018-05-23
drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 May 28 09:30 2018-05-28
drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 May 29 12:24 2018-05-29
drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 Jun  1 11:09 2018-06-01
enter code here
```

Could you please tell me how can i get those files
i am beginner of shell

Comment: I want only those 4 files, if am using 2018* means i gives all files

Comment: What is your criteria for excluding 2018-05-22?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but if you are interested in files starting with `2018`, you can use a pattern with `ls` command.

For example:

```
ls 2018*
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see from your expected ouput, you are trying to print the `directories` and NOT the `files` having `date` format.

If you want to print only the directories of the `date` format having year as current year, you can simply use:

```
ls -lrt |grep ^d |grep "`date +%Y`"
```